# Porque solo me retorna una pelicula de esta API en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer un código que me retorne las peliculas mas populares de una web de cine y tv. Lo estoy haciendo con html y Javascript. Si pido los resultados por console si me devolvia un array con todas las peliculas, pero al hacer un for e imprimir el resultado, solo me devuelve una. No se si me he explicado bien, pongo el codigo que supongo quedara más claro.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
**HTML**

```
<header>
    <span onclick="getPopularMovies()">Películas populares</span>
    <span>Últimas películas</span>
</header>

<main class="movies" id="movies"> 
</main>



<script text="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
const renderMovies = movies => {
    for (const movie of movies){
        document.querySelector('main.movies').innerHTML =`
        <div class="movie">
        <h3>${movie.title}</h3>
        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${movie.poster_path}" alt="Portada">
    </div>
    `
    }
}

const getPopularMovies = ()=>{
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b5138e06a3a9125b8c326498bbeae997&language=es-ES')

    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>{
        const movies = res.results;
        renderMovies(movies);
    })
    .catch(error=>console.error(error))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema básicamente lo tienes en la función `renderMovies`, ya que solo vas a mostrar la ultima película debido a que le estas asignado el ultimo valor del `for`, es decir

```
document.querySelector('main.movies').innerHTML = `...`
```

Lo que deberías de hacer, es concatenar el siguiente div con la película al contenedor `main.movies` haciendo uso del operador `+=`

```
document.querySelector('main.movies').innerHTML += `...`
```

Ejemplo:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let getMoviesSpan = document.getElementById('getMovies')

  getMoviesSpan.addEventListener('click', getPopularMovies);
}


const renderMovies = movies => {
    for (const movie of movies){
        document.querySelector('main.movies').innerHTML +=`
        <div class="movie">
        <h3>${movie.title}</h3>
        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${movie.poster_path}" alt="Portada">
    </div>
    `
    }
}

const getPopularMovies = ()=>{
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b5138e06a3a9125b8c326498bbeae997&language=es-ES')

    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>{
        const movies = res.results;
        renderMovies(movies);
    })
    .catch(error=>console.error(error))
}
```

```html
<header>
    <span id="getMovies">Películas populares</span>
    <span>Últimas películas</span>
</header>

<main class="movies" id="movies">
```